# How to code a Xamarin Forms Page that containes list of projects, where each project can have transactions inside them?

Tags: c#, listview, user-interface, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a Xamarin Forms page that is going to display a document that has some properties and a list of projects. The user should be able to add and remove transactions from each project. From what I can find on the internet, it's not a good practice to nest listview and people are referring to RepeaterView instead. My problem with RepeaterView is that each repeater (project) needs to be interacted with (which I read was not possible), f.x. to add new transactions or delete other transactions.

Here is a link to a screenshot (I don't have enough reputation to post image) of the design for more clarity of what I want to accomplish:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEL6.jpg

How would I set up a page like this? Nested listviews, Repeater with a listview inside or something else?

**EDIT:** here is a example of the model that will be fed to the view:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentProperty1 { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    public string DocumentPropertyN { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectProperty1 { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    public string ProjectPropertyM { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
    public string TransactionProperty1 { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    public string TransactionPropertyM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are the lists made of the same type of object? If so, you could use Grouping in ListView

Comment: Hey @BrunoCaceiro! Thank you for showing interest in helping out. I've edited my post with an example model. I've been thinking about Grouping in ListView but how would you bundle Projects into grouping and the nested transaction into the listview, foreach project? (I have a grouped listview today on another page and I'm familiar with that approach. I'm just unsure how to bundle list into grouping and nested list into the listview).

Comment: You will display only a list of projects? Or Documents?

Comment: The view will display the document with some properties and a list of projects (in the screenshot they are called: Suðurlandsbraut, Verkstæði, Kringlumýrarbraut) and a list of transactions inside each project (in the screenshot those are f.x. Bolalda => Suðurlandsbraut etc.)

Comment: Well, you can check SyncFusion Listview Grouping - https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/grouping, they have a community license as well

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @BrunoCaceiro.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer, for future. Don't forget to mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [SyncFusion Listview Grouping](http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/grouping), they have the functionalities you desire

They have a community license as well